# Sums of Pairs of Integers

Tags: systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Suppose that $a,b,c,d,e$ are integers with the constraint that $a\leq b \leq c \leq d \leq e$.

Also, suppose that the sums of the $5 \choose 2$ = $10$ pairs (i.e. $a+b$, $a+c$, $a+d$, $b+c$, $b+d$, $b+e$, $c+d$, $c+e$, $d+e$) are in some order $25, 27, 28, 31, 32, 34, 35,36,38,42$ (please note that this order is not necessarily respective of the order of the paired sums, i.e. $a+b$ does not necessarily equal $25$, $a+c$ does not necessarily equal $27$, etc.)

Find all possibilities of $a,b,c,d,e$.

The only thing I knew to do was add all the values: $$(a+b) + (a+c) + \cdots + (d+e) = 4(a+b+c+d+e) = 25 + 27 + 28 + 31 + 32 + 34 + 35 + 36 + 38 + 42 = 328 \implies a+b+c+d+e = \frac{328}{4} = 82$$

After that, because of the given inequality constraint, I thought it'd make sense to assign the four smallest numbers (25, 27, 28, 31) to the first four pairs ($a+b, \ldots,b+c$).  But, after solving for each variable, I ended up with $a$ being equal to $\frac{29}{3}$ which contradicts the condition that all 5 variables must be integers.

I'm getting overwhelmed by the number of possible combinations of ($a,b,c,d,e$) especially because of the inequality constraint, which only makes things more difficult. Can someone please show me a more systematic approach to solving this problem?

Appreciate any and all help.

Thanks

-A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: As a start, note that $c=(a+b+c+d+e)-(a+b)-(d+e)$. You know how to find $a+b+c+d+e$. Also, $a+b=25$ and $d+e=42$.

Now everything collapses. We know $a+c$ and $c$, so we know $a$. And so on.  Do check whether the solution you get meets **all** the conditions.

Comment: (This is in answer to a deleted comment, and might as well be kept ffor completeness.)  We must have $a+c=27$, so $a=12$. We have $a+b=25$, so $b=13$. Now use exactly the same kind of reasoning at the other end to find $e$, and then $d$, Now check whether indeed this gives the right set of sums.

Comment: $b+c$ could also equal $27$ right?

Comment: No, the smallest sum must be $a+b$, and the second smallest (since it is different) must be $a+c$. It cannot be $b+c$, since $b+c\gt a+c$,

Comment: Isn't $b+c \geq a+c$?

Comment: But we cannot have equality, since we have been given $10$ distinct sums, and if some two variables were equal, we would have fewer than $10$ distinct sums.

Comment: I got the answer ($a,b,c,d,e$) = ($12,13,15,19,23$). The question asks for all possible combinations, but there should only be one answer in this case, right?

Comment: We check whether this works. It does. The logic we used shows there cannot be any other.